# Is there any scientific info about effects of air pollution during exercise?

Tags: cardio, health-risk, breathing

In my city, some advocacy groups are raising awareness about the dangers of vehicle exhaust nearby parks and other places where people exercise.

However, we couldn't get to "the heart" of the body of knowledge about influences of vehicle air pollution (small particles and gases) specifically over people who are performing physical activity.

Is there any classic study on the subject?

Comment: Not necessarily a classic study, but a [small study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3143527/) showed "a significant decrease in mean Vo2 max, red blood cell count, hemoglobin, hematocrit, and mean corpuscular hemoglobin, as well as significant increase in mean lactate level, white blood cell count and mean corpuscular volume in the higher-polluted than in the lower-polluted area".  This [pdf](http://www.unm.edu/~sschneid/S06%20Exercise%20and%20Air%20Pollution.pdf) discusses dosage, respiratory effects, environmental factors, types of pollutants etc, but does not cite references.

Comment: [This review](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1724353/pdf/v035p00214.pdf) in the British Journal of Sports Medicine surveys the literature and gives a nice discussion of the 6 major air pollutants, and concludes: "Advice to those exercising is of course to stay
away from traffic."  (Complete with references.)

Comment: @BackInShapeBuddy that could be put into an answer! :)

Comment: Hopefully someone with more knowledge in this area than I do will do that :)

Comment: Actually, @BackInShapeBuddy - all you would need to do is expand your comment slightly - Put in that "this review examined the effects of these 6 pollutants", with a little explanation and it would make a great answer. Also for the OP, if you go to Google Scholar and use the search phrase "air pollution impact on exercise" there are a lot of good articles and research studies. They all boil down to "don't run on the road if you can help it" though. :)

Comment: A cycling magazine from back in the 90's (before everything was digitized) ran a good article about this. Interestingly enough it said that dense tree foliage over the street (and a lot of cars, obviously) was the worst because the pollutants tend to stay trapped along the roadway longer than normal. Sorry I can't get you a link or even remember the exact magazine.

Comment: Just an anecdote, but I can say that I spent 3 weeks in a strictly industrial city just outside of Shanghai and the air quality was horrible.  Though elevation was the same as my hometown, I noticed an immediate loss of endurance akin to what I imagine it would be like to train with an elevation mask (exercises performed were high-volume snatches and clean and jerks).  I also felt weak and stifled almost as though I were choking.  After training, I also experienced some of the worst soreness I'd felt, even though I rarely got sore training at home.

Comment: Sport vs. sedentary activity should be compared in a polluted area, not sport in polluted vs. unpolluted area.

Answer (score 3):

Classic studies usually link air pollution with lung conditions.

I find this recent study extremely interesting though:

> Researchers from Vrije Universiteit Brussel in Belgium split a group
>   of 24 runners into two groups: those from urban areas and those from
>   rural areas.
>
> During a 12-week period, the two groups were asked to run three days a
>   week around noon. One group exercised in a rural area, the other group
>   in a busy urban setting. Then, researchers gave the subjects a test to
>   measure their response time and attention span.
>
> They found that those that ran in the city had lower IQ scores and had
>   a higher risk of brain inflammation, according to the Daily Mail.
>   Says http://www.everydayhealth.com/fitness/1212/jogging-outside-could-make-you-dumber-6432.aspx

The original study can be found [here](http://viper.rma.ac.be/pub/Nathalie/bos12.pdf):

Bos, Inge, et al. "Subclinical effects of aerobic training in urban environment." Med Sci Sports Exerc 45.3 (2013): 439-47.

If we check the references of this article, we can find some other interesting ones:

os I, Jacobs L, Nawrot TS, et al. No exercise-induced increase in serum BDNF after
cycling near a major traffic road. Neurosci Lett.2011; 500(2):129-32.

Int Panis L, de Geus B, Vandenbulcke G, et al. Exposure to particulate matter in traffic: A comparison of cyclists and car passengers. Atmos Environ. 2010. 44...

etc

Answer (score 3):

Let me suggest you these articles for a start:

- [G Lippi, GC Guidi, N Maffulli. Air pollution and sports performance in
  Beijing](http://encontroaaarl.com.br/upload/File/Air_Pollution_and_Sports_Performance_in_Beijing.pdf). "There is little doubt that the presence of several air pollutants might be detrimental to athletic performance due to the marked increase (up to 20-fold) in
  ventilatory rate and concomitant nasal and oral breathing. Moreover, mouth breathing often bypasses the nose during strenuous exercise, increasing the deleterious effects of pollutants on health and athletic performance."
- [WE Pierson, DS Covert, JQ Koenig…. Implications of air
  pollution effects on athletic performance](http://europepmc.org/abstract/MED/3088377). "The combination of exercise and pollutant exposure (SO2 or O3) caused a marked bronchoconstriction and reduced ventilatory flow when compared to pollution exposure at rest. In a situation like the Olympic Games where milliseconds and millimeters often determine the success of athletes, air pollution can be an important factor in affecting their performance."
- [AJ Carlisle, NCC Sharp. Exercise and outdoor ambient air pollution](http://bjsm.bmj.com/content/35/4/214.abstract). "Athletes and exercisers should avoid exercising by the road side even though levels of the more noxious air pollutants have been controlled in the United Kingdom. O3 is particularly damaging to athletes."
- [WC Adams. Effects of ozone exposure at ambient air pollution episode levels on exercise performance](http://link.springer.com/article/10.2165/00007256-198704060-00002). "It appears that factors associated with ventilatory limitation impair both V̇O2max and prolonged heavy exercise (> 65% V̇O2max) performance. The observation that ozone exposure, which induces significant pulmonary function impairment, also incurs an increased perceived exertion during submaximal exercise strongly supports this contention."

If not classics, I think they are some of the most cited articles in the subject. Hope it helps.